# How do I find the indices of elements in a vector which are also in another vector using RcppArmadillo?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am stuck trying to find the indices of elements in a vector `x` whose elements are also in another vector `vals` using Rcpp Armadillo. Both `x` and `vals` are of type `arma::uvec`.

In R, this would be straightforward:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,4,2,4,4)
vals <- c(1,4)
which(v %in% vals)
```

I've scanned the Armadillo docs and `find()` was my obvious first try; but it didn't work, since `vals` is a vector. I've also tried `intersect()` but it returns only the first *unique* indices.

What would be a good/efficient way to do this using Armadillo? Do I have to iterate through the elements in `vals` using `find()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick dirty way:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("
  arma::uvec ind(arma::uvec x, arma::uvec y){
   arma::vec a(x.size(), arma::fill::zeros);
   for (auto i:y) a = a +  (x==i);
   return arma::find(a) + 1;
  }
 ", 'RcppArmadillo')

c(ind(v, vals))
[1] 1 2 3 4 6 7
```

Comment: Not even all that dirty!  I could only think of a way via a `hash`, this is shorter!

Comment: Thanks, much more elegant than my interim solution. Does `i:y` mean you loop through the elements in `y` directly instead of through the "index" (as in `for (i = 0; i < y.size(); i++) a = a + (x==y(i))`?

Comment: @Econ21 yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I came up with this solution in the meantime:

```
arma::uvec getIndex(arma::uvec x, arma::uvec y) {
  
  int i, j, k = 0, n = y.size();
  arma::uvec tmp(n);
  
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arma::uvec tmpID = arma::find(x == y(i));
    tmp(i) = tmpID.size();
  }
  
  arma::uvec out(sum(tmp));
  
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arma::uvec id = arma::find(x == y(i));
    for (j = 0; j < id.size(); j++) {
      out(j+k) = id(j);
    }
    k += tmp(i);
  }
  return out;
}
```